# iPhone: finding the currently "highest" view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm coding a MobileSubstrate plugin (a code insertion platform on jailbroken devices) which will hook into safari and a few other apps.

This plugin will have to display an UIActionSheet. But in order to do that I need to find a view to display it in. so far I'm using showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] but it's not the perfect solution.

Is there any way to find the highest view? highest so UIActionSheet doesn't get covered by a view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

keyWindow is the highest view.  You could look through subviews of keyWindow, but in my experience they are unlikely to work well - the tab bar controller is a good example where no direct subview is really great to add a subview to.

What issues are you seeing with using the keywindow?  The primary annoyance would be, that keywindow stuff is not rotated properly in landscape mode...

Comment: well, for example in Tweetie2, when tweetie want's to authorize a new account there is a popup, grey box with ActivityIndicator inside, my action sheet is behind that and can't be "touched". 

since I'm using delegate methods I tried using a loop in the method which creates the ActionSheet and inserted in it [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bringSubviewToFront:actionSheet];

but it didn't work. the popup stays in front of my ActionSheet :/

I hope you get what I mean (my poor english :D)

Comment: Tricky, perhaps you could also override addSubview on UIWindow and anything that is not your window, gets set as a subwindow of your window?

Comment: or maybe a way to get all the views  and then put mine on top of it?

Comment: At the top you would fine the same UIView that is keyWindow.